# Counting simple cycles of complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Counting cycles (even simple ones) in general is hard, but on a bipartite graph it is easier. However a simple search somehow does not come up with the number of simple cycles of $K_{n,n}$.

Comment: See the OEIS sequence: https://oeis.org/A070968 . Found from computing the formula given by @MaxHopkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We begin with the knowledge that there are $\frac{n!(n-1)!}{2}$ undirected hamiltonian cycles in $K_{n,n}$. We also know that simple cycles must have the same number of vertices on the left and right side of the graph. With this in mind, we simply ask how many distinct copies of $K_{i,i}$ exist in our graph. Our graph is complete, so we may simply take the subgraph of any i vertices on the left and right, of which there are ${n \choose i}^2$ copies. Thus in total we have:

$
\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=2}^n {n \choose i}^2 i!(i-1)! =
\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=2}^n \frac{(n)_i^2}{i}
$

where $(n)_i$ is falling factorial. I don't know if there is any way to further simplify this expression.